# JSON.stringify not properly converting object

Tags: javascript, json

So I came across really weird behaviour which I can not seem to fix or find someone with the same issue.
I am working on a plugin system for my application by loading js object from files during startup. I load these using eval and have gotten functions and everything working. However when I try to write my JSON object to a "savefile" its gets written but for some reason an extra Bracket is added

Settings.json

```
{}  "timesToRun": 5,
    "stringForEnd": "We have finished!"
}
```

Plugin.js

```
{
  name: 'My First Plugin',
  author: 'Arcr0s',
  target: 'myData',
  settings:
  {
    timesToRun: 5,
    stringForEnd: 'We have finished!'
  },
  settingsPath: './MyPlugin/Settings.json',
  setup: function() {

  },
  job: function() {
    ConnectionHub.requestHttps('xxxxxxxxx', this.callback);
  },
  callback: function(httpsData) {
    currentSocket.write(httpsData);
  }
}
```

I have tried converting the settings attribute to different objects and ke/value pairs, the output however is always the same.

Snippet from the app

```
let SettingsManager = {
  defaultPath: './Plugins/Settings/',
  loadSettings: function(plugin) {
    var filePath = (plugin.settingsPath != undefined ? plugin.settingsPath : this.defaultPath + plugin.name + ".json");
    console.log(filePath);
    try {
      if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        return fs.readFileSync(filePath,'utf8');
      }
      else {
        this.saveSettings(plugin);
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  },
  saveSettings: function(plugin) {
    var filePath = (plugin.settingsPath != undefined ? plugin.settingsPath : this.defaultPath + plugin.name + ".json");
    fs.writeFile(this.defaultPath, JSON.stringify(plugin.settings,null, "\t"), function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Settingsfile for ' + plugin.name + ' was saved successfully.');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not `JSON.parse` creating the extra bracket, most likely you're calling `SettingsManager.saveSettings` in a loop (or otherwise concurrently), and asynchronous file writing overlaps.

Comment: @Teemu It was indeed a recursive write that was causing the issue. Thank you for the pointer